# Showing that $BPP \subseteq EXP$?

Tags: complexity-theory

I am trying to understand why $BPP \subseteq EXP$. [This question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80106/equivalence-of-machine-m-in-bpp-and-exp) almost gives the answer (simulate $BPP$ machine on all possible toin cosses and then "act accordingly"). However, it is not clear to me what act accordingly means: I am thinking we need to count how many times the probabilistic Turing machine accepts and how many times it rejects and then act upon this information - but how exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A $\mathsf{BPP}$ machine $A$ has randomness complexity $r(n)$ which is polynomial in $n$. Hence, an $\mathsf{EXP}$ machine $B$ can loop over all $2^{r(n)}$ values of the random tape of $A$, simulating $A$ with each random input (each simulation taking polynomial time), and count how many times $A$ accepts or rejects. The overall decision of $A$, then, is whichever of the two counters contains a larger value at the end of this process.

Interestingly, the same reasoning also explains why [$\mathsf{PP}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PP_(complexity)) is contained in $\mathsf{EXP}$.